# Question about quotient groups and cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to determine which representation to choose to form the quotient groups.

For instance, if G = $Z$$_4$ × $Z$$_4$ and let N be the cyclic subgroup generated by (3, 2). Show that G/N is isomorphic to $Z$$_4$

In the book it said G/N has four cosets namely N, N+(0,1), N+(0,2), N+(0,3)

How did they the choose the specific representatives? Would it be correct if I choose the representatives as (1,3), (1, 2), (3,2) and (2,2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The representatives can be any ones w¡you want as long as they're not related to each other. 
$$N=\left\lbrace (3,2),(2,0),(1,2),(0,0)\right\rbrace$$
Two of the elements you chose: $(3,2)$ and $(1,2)$ are related to each other, as $(3,2)-(1,2)$ belongs to $N$ (actually they both belong to $N$. So those you chose don't form a valid set.

A general way to do this, the most simple way, is to start be knowing the number of different cosets, by Lagranges theorem, that will be the size of the group 16 divided by the size of the subgroup (4), so 4.
Then we start choosing by picking the most simple one $(0,0)$ this will give $N$ as the coset, so we have:

$$N+(0,0)=\left\lbrace (3,2),(2,0),(1,2),(0,0)\right\rbrace$$
The next one must not contain the previous one, so any element not contained in $N$ will be valid. For simplicty, I would choose $(1,0)$

$$N+(1,0)=\left\lbrace (0,2),(3,0),(2,2),(1,0)\right\rbrace$$

For the next one we do the same, the next one must not be contained in $N$, and now must not be related with $(1,0)$, so it must not be contained in the last coset. One possible example is $(0,1)$

$$N+(0,1)=\left\lbrace (3,3),(2,1),(1,3),(0,1)\right\rbrace$$

And now for the fourth and last one, we do just the same. It musn't be related to any of the previous ones, that means it musn't be contained in any of the previous cosets. For example, we can pick $(3,1)$, which is just the first one I see that is not in the previous cosets.

$$N+(3,1)=\left\lbrace (2,3),(1,1),(0,3),(3,1)\right\rbrace$$

As you can see, the cosets are a disjoint union of the group, and now we have a valid set of representatives:

$$C=\left\lbrace (0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(3,1)\right\rbrace$$

This could be a general way to do this when you have small groups. If they're larger, you will have to be a little ingenous to come up with not related elements. But in elementary group theory, which I guess it's the one you're taking, that's generally easy.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Other coset representatives may work, however the ones you picked unfortunately do not.  $(1,2)$ is in $N$ already, since $(3,2)+(3,2)+(3,2)=(1,2)$.  But also $(3,2)$ is in $N$.  Hence they are both the same coset, namely $(0,0)+N$.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the fact that $\;(3,2)\;,\;\;(1,2)\,$ are in the same coset, since

$$(3,2)-(1,2)=(2,0)\in N:=\langle(3,2)\rangle=\{(0,0)\,,\,(3,2)\,,\,(2,0)\,,\,(1,2)\}\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way $N$ is generated, you know for an element $(a,b)$ of $N,$ that $a$ can be any element of $Z_4$ and that $b$ is completely determined by $a$ using the rule $b=2a\mod{4}.$  Hence the cosets will be sets where $b$ differs from the value given by this rule by a constant amount.  This is why $(0,1),$ $(0,2),$ and $(0,3)$ are natural coset representatives to choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you interested not only $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4$, but general methods, the following article may be useful:

Todd, J.A., Coxeter, H.S.M.
A practical method for enumerating cosets of a finite abstract group. 
Proc. Edinb. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 5, 26-34 (1936).

See also

Magnus, W., Karrass, A., Solitar, D.
Combinatorial group theory: Presentations of groups in terms of generators and relations.
New York-London-Sydney: Interscience Publishers, 1966,

Coxeter, H.S.M., Moser, W.O.J.
Generators and relations for discrete groups. 
Springer-Verlag, 1972.